# Unable to filter an array with multiple objects in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am able to filter below array

```
this.items = [
  'Amsterdam',
  'Bogota',
  'India'
];
```

I am using this code in my `list.ts` file:

```
if (val && val.trim() != '') {
  this.items = this.items.filter((item) => {
    return (item.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
  })
}
```

Requirement - I am fetching data from JSON which is returning array with multiple results, image of html and console shown below. Problem is how do I filter this:

I am fetching data from JSON using this code below:

```
this._listProduct.listProduct().subscribe(data => {
  this.list = data;
 console.log(data);
```

I want to filter `this.list`:

Image: `list.html` and of `console.log`:

[image]

`list.html` code for your reference:

```
<ion-content padding>
    <ion-grid>


        <ion-searchbar (ionInput)="getItems($event)"></ion-searchbar>


       <ion-row>
          <ion-col>Id</ion-col>
          <ion-col>Product/Service</ion-col> 
          <ion-col>Name</ion-col>
          <ion-col>Unit</ion-col>
          <ion-col>Category</ion-col>
          <ion-col>HSN</ion-col>
          <ion-col>Posting head</ion-col>
          <ion-col>Rate</ion-col>
          <ion-col>Type</ion-col>
          <ion-col>SACCode</ion-col>
          <ion-col>Tax Collected</ion-col>
          <ion-col></ion-col>
       </ion-row> 

       <ion-row *ngFor = "let list of list"> 
          <ion-col>{{list.ID}}</ion-col>
          <ion-col>{{list.PRODUCTSERVICE}}</ion-col> 
          <ion-col>{{list.NAME}}</ion-col>
          <ion-col>{{list.UNIT}}</ion-col>
          <ion-col>{{list.CATEGORY}}</ion-col>
          <ion-col>{{list.HSN}}</ion-col>
          <ion-col>{{list.POSTINGHEAD}}</ion-col>
          <ion-col>{{list.RATE}}</ion-col>
          <ion-col>{{list.TYPE}}</ion-col>
          <ion-col>{{list.SACCODE}}</ion-col>
          <ion-col>{{list.TAX_CONNECTED}}</ion-col>
          <ion-col>
             <ion-icon ios="ios-create" md="md-create" (click)="editProduct(list)"></ion-icon>
             <ion-icon ios="ios-close-circle" md="md-close-circle" (click)="deleteProduct(list)"></ion-icon></ion-col> 
       </ion-row>   
    </ion-grid>  
</ion-content>
```

### Update 1

I tried using below code but it is giving me error:

> list.toLowerCase is not a function

Code tried:

```
if (val && val.trim() != '') {
  this.list = this.list.filter((list) => {
    return (list.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
  })
}
```

Comment: what do you want to filter? you got the array of objects in response and iterating the same in HTML. what else you want?

Comment: i want to filter this entire array when i type in the search box, when i am typing only matching rows should be seen,i want to search from all objects

Comment: First, you're using the same variable list to refer to the list of objects, and to an element inside the list of objects. Pick a better name, like `product`, if that's what the list contains. You're calling toLowerCase() on the elements of the list. But the list doesn't contain strings, it contains objects. So that makes no sense. You need to decide on which property(ies) of the product you want to filter: name? category?

Comment: i would like to filter on `name`,`productservice` and `category`

Comment: Try doing it then.

Comment: how to do it ? is my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add more condition in the filter to filter the object. PFB the code where the search term will be compared with name, product service and category.

```
this.items = this.items.filter((item) => {
    return ((item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1) || 
(item.productservice .toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1) || 
(item.category .toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1));
  })
```

Comment: as per ypur guidance i coded like this - `    if (val && val.trim() != '') {
    this.list = this.list.filter((item) => {
      return ((item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1) || 
  (item.productservice .toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1) || 
  (item.category .toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1));
    })
  }`  but when i type anything on search box i am geting this - `Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined`

Comment: check whether the items have the collection of objects with name, productservice and category properties

Comment: you can refer this link for working sample https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-array-example

Comment: it has name,productservice and category..i have seen your example, i am able to search from 1 array object, problem is how to search from multiple..can we chat ?

Comment: If you have multiple array of objects, merge into single array and add condition in filter method to filter the objects on display. yeah you can reach me at prithiviraj1991@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

initially duplicate the response...

```
this.copylist = this.list;

search(val) {
this.list = this.copylist;
if (val && val.trim() != '') {
  this.list = this.list.filter((item) => {
    return (item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
  })
}
```

}